# Canvas tag is shifted on my page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to simply track the mouse over my canvas tag, and log how far it is from the center of a circle.  The problem is, it's off slightly.

When I'm on the right side of the circle, the mouse has to be about 1 cm inside the circle before I show a distance of r (radius = 200).  When I'm on the left side of the circle, I have to be about 1cm outside the circle to register a distance of r.  It's like the circle is shifted a tad to the right.

I tried reproducing this with [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTyjZ/), but oddly enough, the fiddle is perfect; it's spot on.

So I guess my question is, what would cause my canvas tag to be shifted about 1cm on my page (but not on the fiddle).  Do I need a better DOCTYPE?  I reproduce my entire source below.  I've tested in both FF and Chrome—same result.

**EDIT**

I also tried `<!DOCTYPE html>` to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            var context = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(250, 250);
            context.arc(250, 250, 200, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            context.closePath();
            context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,100,0)';
            context.fill();


            $("canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
                var x = e.pageX;
                var y = e.pageY;

                var dist = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - 250.0, 2) + Math.pow(y - 250.0, 2)));

                console.log(dist);
            });
        });


    </script>


</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800">

    </canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems adding `*{margin:0, padding:0, border:0}` solves the problem, however, Im not sure where the extra padding is coming from.

Comment: @Jesse - thanks - I had that same idea while driving home.  That's as valid an answer as any, so throw it up so I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, actually it seems that `body{margin:0, padding:0, border:0}` does the trick.
Also, on a side note, rather than calling all those Math functions the following would be simpler and faster:

```
var x = e.pageX - 250;
var y = e.pageY - 250;
var dist = Math.round(Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y));
```

Also, using a [css reset kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset) would probably solve all your problems for all browsers.

I was curious, so I checked the defaults:

```
var bodyElement = $('body');

// Get the padding
var widthPadding = bodyElement.css('padding-left') + bodyElement.css('padding-right');
var heightPadding = bodyElement.css('padding-top') + bodyElement.css('padding-bottom');
console.log(widthPadding + ", "+ heightPadding);
// Get the margins
var widthMargin = bodyElement.css('margin-left') + bodyElement.css('margin-right');
var heightMargin = bodyElement.css('margin-top') + bodyElement.css('margin-bottom');
console.log(widthMargin + ", "+ heightMargin);
// Get the borders
var widthBorder = bodyElement.css('border-left-width') + bodyElement.css('border-right-width');
var heightBorder = bodyElement.css('border-top-width') + bodyElement.css('border-bottom-width');
console.log(widthBorder + ", "+ heightBorder);
```

The output was like this on FF 9.0.1 was:

```
0px0px, 0px0px 
8px8px, 8px8px <-- So obviously you only need to reset the margins to 0
0px0px, 0px0px
```

Comment: Works great - thank you.  I'll leave this open a bit to see if anyone can provide some more info on where this default padding/margin comes from

Comment: *"Also, using a css reset kit would probably solve all your problems for all browsers."* Gosh, what a wonderful world that would be.